Why is the PDF in my object element not loading on mobile?
I am creating a webpage that will display a bunch of programs my company will be hosting. The programs page has a picture and small description of the program, and when they click the learn more button, a modal should pop up displaying the PDF of the programs details. I works on desktop just fine, however, the PDF will not load on mobile.
Developer tools on mobile just displays the overlay on the page, if I put a red border around the object element, that red border displays, but not the pdf.
Here is the formal for each
 <div class="program">
                              <h2>One Billion Blueberries</h2>
                              <div class="program-img-container">
                                    <img src="../img/blueberries.jpg" alt="bushel of blueberries">
                              </div>
                              <p class="program-description">Help maintain healthy populations of edible berries on human properties in hopes that they will spread back into the wild, giving them a fighting chance against invasives. </p>
                              <div class="learn-more-btn program-learn-more-btn">LEARN MORE</div>

                              <div class="program-modal">
                                    <object type="application/pdf" data="../pdfs/OneBillionBlueberries.pdf" height="700" width="1000"></object>
                                    <div class="modal-overlay"></div>
                              </div>
                        </div>

styling:
.program-modal {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: fixed;
      display: none;
      justify-content: center;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 2;
}

.program object{
      width: 60%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 2;
}

.modal-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.618);
      z-index: 0;
}

JAVASCRIPT for opening pdfs:
//PROGRAMS MODALS
const learnMoreButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("program-learn-more-btn");
const programModals = document.getElementsByClassName("program-modal")

//OPEN PROGRAM PDFs
for (let i= 0; i < learnMoreButtons.length; i++) {
      learnMoreButtons[i].onclick = () => {
            if (programModals[i].style.display !== "flex") {
                  programModals[i].style.display = "flex"
            }
      };
}

//CLOSE PROGRAM PDF
for (let i = 0; i < programModals.length; i++) {
      programModals[i].querySelector(".modal-overlay").onclick = () => {
            if (programModals[i].style.display !== "none") {
                  programModals[i].style.display = "none";
            }
      };
 }


I tried changing the width settings of the object on both the html file and the css file but that didn't work.
